# I need a full example for delphi 7 application manifest file to enable finding files with a very long path names

Tags: delphi

I have a 32 bit delphi 7 application that runs as administrator user on a windows server 2008 r2 machine.
My application cannot find files where path is longer than MAX_PATH.
I tried FindFirst, FindFirstFileW, Find etc.. and also try to find with a prepend of \?\ but Nothing happens.
I red about an ability to compile a manifest file to enable long file name to a specific application but this is also seams to be not working. 
Can some one give me a full manifest file to handle long file names ?
Any other suggestions will be gladly excepted.

this is my compiled manifest which did nothing for my application.
This manifest was compiled to an *.rc file and declared in my application

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="LongPathP.exe" version="3.1.0.0" processorArchitecture="*"/>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls" version="6.0.0.0" publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df" language="*" processorArchitecture="*"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false"/>
        </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
  <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
    <application>
        <windowsSettings xmlns:ws2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">
            <ws2:longPathAware>true</ws2:longPathAware>
        </windowsSettings>

      <!--The ID below indicates application support for Windows Vista -->
      <supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}"/>
      <!--The ID below indicates application support for Windows 7 -->
      <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"/>
    </application>
  </compatibility>
</assembly>
```

Comment: You'll need to use the Unicode API. Which means making sure you call the W function. The RTL for Delphi 7 doesn't. Consider upgrading to modern Delphi.

Comment: There is no manifest option in Windows Server 2008 R2 to enable longer file paths. That feature was added in Windows 10 v1607 instead. See [Maximum Path Length Limitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/naming-a-file#maximum-path-length-limitation) on MSDN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following program written with Delphi 7 is able to display files in directory structures with a depth far greater than MAX_PATH. Please compile and run it on your system to check whether you still cannot find files with very long path names. The program scans recursively through a directory tree.

If the problem persists, there is probably something wrong at your end.

Call the program like this: `FindFiles.exe C:\Folder\*.txt`

```
{$WARN SYMBOL_PLATFORM OFF}

program FindFiles;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses SysUtils, Windows, StrUtils;

(* ---- *)

function LastPos (const chSearch: Char; sStr: String) : Integer;

var
    iLen, iPos : Integer;

begin
    Result := Pos (chSearch, sStr);

    if (Result > 0) then
    begin
        iLen := Length (sStr);

        repeat
            if (Result < iLen) then
            begin
                iPos := PosEx (chSearch, sStr, Result + 1);

                if (iPos > 0) then
                    Result := iPos;
            end { if }
            else iPos := 0;
        until (iPos = 0);
    end; { if }
end; { LastPos }

(* ---- *)

procedure SearchDir (const sPath, sMask: String);

var
    hFindFile : THandle;
    FindData : WIN32_FIND_DATAW;
    psFileName : PWideChar;

begin
    FillChar (FindData, SizeOf (WIN32_FIND_DATAW), #0);

    hFindFile := FindFirstFileW (PWideChar (WideString (sPath + sMask)),
                                 FindData);

    if (hFindFile <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) then
    begin
        repeat
            psFileName := @FindData.cFileName [0];

            if (FindData.dwFileAttributes and FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY = 0) then
                WriteLn (WideString (psFileName) +
                         Format (' (%d)', [Length (sPath) - 5]));
        until (FindNextFileW (hFindFile, FindData) = false);

        Win32Check (FindClose (hFindFile));
    end; { if }

    hFindFile := FindFirstFileW (PWideChar (WideString (sPath + '*.*')),
                                 FindData);

    if (hFindFile <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) then
    begin
        repeat
            psFileName := @FindData.cFileName [0];

            if (FindData.dwFileAttributes and FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY <> 0) then
            begin
                if (psFileName^ = '.') or (psFileName = '..') then
                    Continue;

                SearchDir (sPath + psFileName + '\', sMask);
            end; { if }
        until (FindNextFileW (hFindFile, FindData) = false);

        Win32Check (FindClose (hFindFile));
    end; { if }
end; { SearchDir }

(* ---- *)

const
    cParamErrMsg = 'Unable to retrieve start folder and search mask from "%s"';

var
    sFolder, sMask : String;
    iPos : Integer;

begin { FindFiles }
    WriteLn;

    if (ParamCount <> 1) then
    begin
        WriteLn ('The 1st parameter must be a folder name including a search pattern');
        Halt ($FF);
    end; { if }

    sFolder := ParamStr (1);

    iPos := LastPos ('\', sFolder);

    if (iPos > 0) then
    begin
        SetLength (sFolder, iPos);

        if (iPos < Length (ParamStr (1))) then
            sMask := Copy (ParamStr (1), iPos + 1, Length (ParamStr (1)) - iPos)
    end; { if }

    if (sMask = '') or (sFolder = '') then
    begin
        WriteLn (Format (cParamErrMsg, [ParamStr (1)]));
        Halt ($FD);
    end; { if }

    try
        SearchDir ('\\?\' + sFolder, sMask);

    except
        on E:Exception do
            WriteLn (Format ('Error: %s', [E.Message]));
    end; { try / except }

    if (DebugHook <> 0) then
    begin
        WriteLn;
        Write ('Press [Enter] to continue ...');
        ReadLn;
    end; { if }
end.
```